# How do I stop GUI?

Tags: command-line

I need to enter the command line alone with no GUI to install the official NVIDIA drivers. I'm trying to get my computer to work over HDMI and someone on Youtube shows how but you have to be in the Nvidia settings program.

Answer (score 30):

To do that just follow this:

1. Go to CLI mode:

   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Stop GUI service on Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm stop
   ```

   or if you're using a version of Ubuntu before 11.10, run:

   ```
   sudo service gdm stop
   ```

Comment: Perhaps add more Display managers, for the other variants of Ubuntu.

Comment: running this from terminal `sudo service lightdm stop` worked for me.

Comment: This simple service stopping and starting works - but it is the full canonical mode change? In the old times one entered non-graphical mulit-user mode by 'runlevel 3' and back graphical by 'runlevel 5'. With systemd this should translate to (A) `systemctl isolate multi-user` and (B) `systemctl isolate graphical`. (A) indeed closes GUI, (B) brings up the login screen again - which however yields errors ("Could not connect to bus session: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/bus: Connection refused") when trying to login. Why?

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

to stop the GUI and

```
sudo service gdm start
```

to start it again

Comment: If you use kubuntu change `gdm` with `kdm` :)

Comment: I'll accept yours because my question was too way specific. Actually I needed to run telinit 1 to completely disable not required processes.

Comment: With Ubuntu 18.04 this turns it off but doesn't turn it back on...any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

If your purpose is to temporarily disable GUI - you can stop the `lightdm` service ( or whichever greeter you're using ) with `sudo service lightdm stop` (14.04 and earlier) or `sudo systemctl stop lightdm` (since 15.04) from tty1, as shown by others already.

If your purpose to boot into command line for extended period of time between reboots, you can open `/etc/default/grub` with the choice of your text editor. I personally use `nano`, so for me the command would be `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. Now, find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"`. Or you can create two lines, one commented , one uncommented like so:

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Once necessary, just uncomment the line for which mode you wanna enter. Upon completing editing the `/etc/default/grub` file, save it, and run `sudo update-grub` to make the configurations loaded into the actual  `grub.cfg` file. Reboot, and you should enter the command line directly.

Answer (score 2):

Start by logging out and striking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, then log on.

On Kubuntu stopping the GUI can be done through `sudo /etc/init.d/kdm stop`. On Ubuntu this will probably be `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop`.

Enter your password when prompted.

`dm` stands for Display Manager, check `ls /etc/init.d/` which `dm` is available when it is not `gdm`.

To restart it just change `stop` to `start`.

You probably automatically change to the GUI, if not strike: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: obysr's `lightdm` sounds familiar. That would make the command: `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`

Answer (score 1):

I know you are not asking this specifically, but you need to install the nvidia-current driver.

You can do this from a gui. Just run `jockey-gtk` or search for "Additional Drivers" from the dash. Once it is installed, open Nvidia Settings and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could open gnome-terminal and type `sudo telinit 1`.  This would drop you to run level 1(single user mode) and kill the gui services.

Comment: it's not happening. I typed sudo init 3 but nothing changed.

Comment: it was sudo telinit 1, then choose root.

Comment: @bertmanphx: you are not aware of ubuntu startup process and  runlevels used.

Comment: @dierre: I think it is not correct to edit answers in the core, like changing 3 to 1. This invalidates OP intentions and my objection.

Comment: Well the answer was actually useful so I thought to correct the wrong parts.

Comment: btw the editing was accepted so I don't know how to behave right now. Is it rigth or wrong?

Comment: @dierre - if you are unsure, ask on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

to stop GUI from auto-loading

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user
```

to start it again:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical
```