# How do I stop the GUI (in Kubuntu 21.10)

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, lightdm, gdm, 21.10

I need to stop the GUI and access a TTY for the NVIDIA drivers. I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148321/how-do-i-stop-gui). However, when I tried `sudo service lightdm stop` (or the same with `gdm`), it said this:

```
$ sudo service lightdm stop
Failed to stop lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service not loaded.
$ sudo service gdm stop
Failed to stop gdm.service: Unit gdm.service not loaded.
```

I'd prefer not have to mess with Grub, as I only need to stop the GUI once. So, how do I stop the GUI to use a TTY with no GUI running at all in Kubuntu 21.10?

Note: I know [how to access a TTY](https://askubuntu.com/a/66198/1438484). But once I'm in the TTY, I need to stop the GUI, as the NVIDIA driver installer wants me to be in a TTY *and have the GUI not running*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kubuntu uses `sddm` as the display manager. So

`sudo service sddm stop`

should do it.

Comment: Why not use systemd's commands directly instead of wrapper and run `systemctl stop sddm.service`?

Comment: @valisstillwithMonica fewer letters to type

Answer (score 7):

For me, doing the following (in a TTY) worked to stop the GUI.

```
$ sudo init 3
```

After I ran that, I was able to successfully install my NVIDIA GPU driver.

Answer (score 5):

You can also ask systemd to get into *`multi-user.target`* by using below command:

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

And after all TTY-based operations get finished jump back to graphical session by

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to stop the GUI to access a text-only terminal.

CTRL+ALT+F3 gets you to TTY3
CTRL+ALT+F4 gets you to TTY4
... and so on

Comment: IIRC the installer for Nvidia drivers will still complain, since the GUI is running in the background.

Comment: Yes, I realize those comments are now-deleted, but I need the GUI not running at all (so completely off, not just in a different TTY) for the NVIDIA GPU drivers.